# PHP not working in django template

Tags: php, html, django

**The code is:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    aaa
    <?php
        echo "hello";
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried it within the `test.php` file under `/Library/WebServer/Documents/test.php`
and it works at `http://localhost/test.php`.

When I put it in the `index.php` file within the `project/app/template/app/index.php`
Only the "aaa" shows up at `localhost/app/` and the PHP is not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you expect this to work? Django is not PHP.

Comment: @DanielRoseman but couldnt I create html? If so, why not create php?

Comment: But PHP and HTML are not at all the same thing. And I cannot think of a single reason why you would want to do this. Django templates have their own language, and you should absolutely not need to write PHP inside them.

Comment: @Ales I am new to both of them so you really don't need to contempt other like this. I want to create template and want to divide each template into navigation and footer.html so that I could just include them in each of my page. If php is not the right choice, could you recommend how should I realize this?

Answer (score 0):

Django server is not capable of running php scripts. It's server isn't a HTTP server. You need HTTP servers like Apache, nginx to run php scripts.

Since you are running a localhost server this would not help you. At a production level though you can run your php script by configuring django to run on the HTTP servers like Apache.

Here is the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) that will help you configure django with an HTTP server so that you can run your php script inside a Django template.

Comment: No, don't recommend this. OP is completely confused about what web development is; we shouldn't recommend running an HTTP server in development just so they can do something they obviously shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Please do not encourage anyone to use PHP inside Django, this is wrong on so many levels.

Answer (score 0):

I have not find some way to realize the non-repeating header and footer functionality in django. It is realized by template inheritance.

[template inheritance](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/templates.html)

Please point out if this is not the right way to do so.